# Is there any sniff available for valid variable name when preset is Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpcodesniffer, sniffer

I've integrated this library into my existing Laravel project, and it's been performing exceptionally well. However, I've encountered a challenge related to adhering to camel case variable naming conventions. I attempted to address this concern by utilizing available sniffs like

```
PHP_CodeSniffer\Standards\Zend\Sniffs\NamingConventions\ValidVariableNameSniff
PHP_CodeSniffer\Standards\Squiz\Sniffs\NamingConventions\ValidVariableNameSniff
```

Unfortunately, both of these sniffs also flag variable usages such as $user->first_name. I'm keen to learn if there exists an alternative sniff or a method to incorporate this insight into my project while maintaining accuracy in variable naming conventions.